# Camera capture button in Android

Tags: android, camera

I'm using `hardware.Camera` component in my application but there is  a capture button missing. Is it possible to use default capture button, the same as when we start camera as activity from Intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "default capture button". When "we start camera as activity from Intent", the activity that appears will be one from hundreds, if not thousands, of available camera apps. This includes both apps pre-installed on Android devices and apps that are installed by users.